# Regular Expression For File Name in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression to parse two sections out of the file name for the .resx files in my project. There is one main file called "UiText.resx" and then many translation .resx files with convention "UiText.ja-JP.resx". I need both the "UiText" and the "ja-JP" out of the latter string, as we do have other resx files that don't have to be for UiText (e.g. I have some files named "ExceptionText.resx").

The pattern I'm using right now (which works, it just requires a little extra coding after) is `"(?<=\.)((.*?)(?=\.resx))"`. For the example above, "UiText.ja-JP.resx" gets me a match set in C# of "UiText.", "ja-JP.", "ja-JP.", ".resx"

Of course I am able to just take the first occurrence of "ja-JP." and "UiText." from this set and massage it to what I want, but I'd rather just have a cleaner "UiText" "ja-JP" and be done with it.

I figure I'll probably have to have at least two different patterns for this, so that is OK. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What changes in your convention for the files that you want?  In particular, are all prefixed with "UiText" exactly, or some variants thereof?  As stated, it seems to me that "UiText" is more of a filter to pick out the files you need, not something you really need to extract.  Is this correct?

Comment: So, do I understand it right that file names you want to parse fall under `<no-dots>.<no-dots>.resx` pattern? Then use `var ms = Regex.Matches(s, @"^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.resx$").Cast<Match>(); var TextType = ms.Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToList(); var LangCode = ms.Select(x => x.Groups[2].Value).ToList();`

Comment: If you have a single file name, use this `^(?:([^.]*)\.)+resx(?!\S)`, use the capture collection of group 1 to get all the parts up to `.resx`. Doesn't matter how many parts there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `UiText` seems to be constant you can use this regex to extract just `js-JP` into $1:

```
^UiText\.(.+?)\.resx$
```

https://regex101.com/r/XKvwHA/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your needs correctly, then the main reason you need "UiText" is not because you have any value for the term itself, but rather because you need to filter your files.  The real term you need to play around with is "ja-JP", which changes for the files you need.

If I'm correct, try this regex:

```
(?<=UiText\.).+(?=\.resx)
```

Used in C# as follows:

```
var fileName = "UiText.ja-JP.resx";

var result = new Regex(@"(?<=^UiText\.).+(?=\.resx$)").Match(fileName).Value;
```

A little explanation:

- `(?<=^UiText\.)`  Start of string must begin exactly with "UiText."
- `.+` Any number of characters (but at least one)
- `(?=\.resx$)` End of string must end with ".resx"

Any file that doesn't meet your criteria will return an empty string for 'result'.